# What are the data.* references in {wrap}bootstrap themes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I purchased a {wrap}bootstrap theme.  In the process of moving the assets into my Rails 2.3.x app (don't laugh), I notice there are many places in the views and helpers where some `data` object is accessed.  For instance:

```rb
  def active(id)
    if data.page.menukey == id
        return 'active'
    end

    return ''
  end
```

Where is this `data` object defined?  Is it just a clumsy placeholder for people implementing the theme to replace with their own objects?

Answer (score 0):

The `data` object you see in {wrap}bootstrap themes comes from MiddleMan "[local data](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/local-data/)".  MiddleMan is not required to implement a {wrap}bootstrap theme.  You may wish to search and replace every instance of `data` with something meaningful to your application.